# Google Api Error: forbidden: The caller does not have permission - The caller does not have permission

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play-console, ionic-appflow

In android deployment from ionic appflow getting below error

> Google Api Error: forbidden: The caller does not have permission - The caller does not have permission

- Added service account with service account user role, owner
- Grant Admin access in play console.
- upload the json key to appflow

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?  I am facing same issue

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had a very similar issue when deploying to the playstore with fastlane on the command line. I think my solution will work for you too.

Here's my full error message from the command line:

```
[!] Google Api Error: Invalid request - The caller does not have permission
```

So what does it mean? Well, since it is a Google API Error we can narrow things down a lot. That means that the error is on the Google Cloud side and that our fastlane installation, our ruby installation, our OS and so on are all probably fine.

#### Fix it in the Google Play Console

Go to the Google Play Console and find the API Access Section under Setup -> API Access in the navigation panel on the left

[image]

On the API Access page click the “View Play Console permissions” link. You may have to scroll down a bit. It’s going to be attached to the service account that you made for your app.

[image]

Click on the “Account permissions” tab

[image]

Click the Admin checkmark in the “App Access” section and this will fix your error.

[image]

I have opened a Github Issue here:
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20890

To request that this information be added to the documentation. Feel free to checkout that Github issue as well.

Comment: I am not the owner of Google Play Console account but i am given admin role and all permissions are granted, but still i am getting this permission error. Can you tell me what should I do? thanks

Comment: Contact your administrator, send them these instructions and see if they can un block you. Best of luck!!

Comment: You may also notice in the last screen cap that there is an "App Permissions" and  a "Permissions Group" tab. What I would do in this situation is I would check out those tabs and just max permissions as much as I can to see if the issue will go away, and then once I can get rid of the issue, start putting some restrictions back slowly until the  error re-emerges. That way I can still remain as restrictive and "safe" as possible without the error, but first I just max out to see if I can get rid of the error message.